# Magento 2: how to get swatch options in custom product list on detail page?

Tags: magento2, swatches

I added my custom product list in detail page, the collection is properly displaying but now I want to display swatches in that list. is there any way to make it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Put below code in your **referenceblock** in **XML** file.

```
<block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable"
     name="category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable"
     template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml"
     ifconfig="catalog/frontend/show_swatches_in_product_list">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurable_view_model"
                xsi:type="object">Magento\Swatches\ViewModel\Product\Renderer\Configurable</argument>
        </arguments>
</block>
```

Put below code in your **phtml** file.

```
$blocks = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.product.type.details.renderers.configurable');
echo $blocks->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();
```